# Resizable UIImage where outside stretches and inside is kept the same

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to create a "grip" for a vertical bar in my app, to show the user that they can swipe on the view. I'd like to just use a small version of the image, which has the grip and 1 px above and below it which is the background for the rest of the bar. So:

```
ssss          ssss
gggg  becomes ssss
ssss          gggg
              ssss
              ssss
```

The method `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` allows you to tell iOS not adjust the outside edge, but is there a way to tell it to not adjust the interior and stretch with the exterior?

I've tried specifying a oversized cap inset, `UIEdgeInsetsMake(29.0f, 0.0f, 29.0f, 0.0f)` and that resulted in the grip being at the top of the image's frame, but otherwise is the correct stretching behavior I'm looking for. I just need to have the grip part centered in the frame.

Full code for those interested (this results in the grip being repeated across the whole length):

```
gripBar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"grip"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)]];
gripBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, gripWidth, fullHeight);
[view gripBar];
```

**Update:** working code based on chosen answer

```
@implementation GripBar

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        UIImageView *bar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"gripback"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)]];
        bar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self addSubview:bar];

        UIImageView *grip = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grip"]];
        grip.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        grip.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        [self addSubview:grip];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably to make your grip part be a (small-height, but full-width) subview of a larger bar view whose background stretches or tiles. You can keep the grip part centered in your larger view by, for example, autoresize masks.