# Resizable UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, resizable

I know this topic has lots of Q&A, I read them all and still couldn't get it going...
I'm trying to stretch an image, while keeping its rounded edges.

This is my image (104x77px):

[image]

this is the code I'm using:

```
UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBg"];
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake((bg.size.height - 1)/2, (bg.size.width - 1)/2, (bg.size.height - 1)/2, (bg.size.width - 1)/2);
bg = [bg resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 50, 44)];
imgView.image = bg;

UIImageView *imgView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 70, 250, 44)];
imgView2.image = bg;

[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[self.view addSubview:imgView2];
```

and this is the problem:

As you can see each image has different edges.
What am I doing wrong?!

[image]

Comment: The problem with the image views is that they are smaller (in height) than the original image (and the 1st is narrower too). Resizable images are meant to be larger than the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever any scaling is involved, images of two different dimensions can't look quite the same. However you can break your image into three parts: the left corners, the middle section (just the parallel lines), and the right corners.

Now to create image views of different sizes, you'll keep the left and right parts constant, and scale the middle section, which won't look distorted as long as you keep the heights constant.

Note that I have give the height of `fitInRect` as 77 because that's the original image height. You can change this to, say, 44 but keep the number constant for all image views.
Finally, `widthToPreserve` HAS to be a minimum of 34 (which means the overall Rect width has to be 68 or more) because that's the width of the rounded edge in the original image.

Of course, you can simply all this by having a smaller image, if your target image view height is 44.

This code works:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];

    UIImageView *view1 = [self getImageViewFromImage:img widthToPreserve:34 fitInRect:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 77)];

    UIImageView *view2 = [self getImageViewFromImage:img widthToPreserve:34 fitInRect:CGRectMake(20, 120, 250, 77)];

    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    [self.view addSubview:view2];

}

-(UIImageView*)getImageViewFromImage:(UIImage*)image widthToPreserve:(float)width fitInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGImageRef left, middle, right;
    CGRect leftRect, middleRect, rightRect;
    UIImage *leftImage, *middleImage, *rightImage;
    UIImageView *leftView, *middleView, *rightView;

    // calculate CGRect values for the original image
    leftRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, image.size.height);
    middleRect = CGRectMake(width, 0, image.size.width - 2*width, image.size.height);
    rightRect = CGRectMake(image.size.width - width, 0, width, image.size.height);

    left = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], leftRect);
    middle = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], middleRect);
    right = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rightRect);


    leftImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:left];
    middleImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:middle];
    rightImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:right];

    leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:leftImage];
    middleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:middleImage];
    rightView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:rightImage];

    //make your image subviews, with scaling on the middle view
    [leftView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, rect.size.height)];
    [middleView setFrame:CGRectMake(width, 0, rect.size.width - 2*width, rect.size.height)];
    [rightView setFrame:CGRectMake(rect.size.width - width, 0, width, rect.size.height)];

//add your 3 subviews into a single image view
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [imgView addSubview:leftView];
    [imgView addSubview:middleView];
    [imgView addSubview:rightView];


    CGImageRelease(left);
    CGImageRelease(middle);
    CGImageRelease(right);

    return imgView;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a stretchable image

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:5];
```

As maddy points out this is deprecated in iOS 5, for those of us poor souls having to support iOS 4.3 this is what we use.

Comment: `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` was deprecated in iOS 5.0. `resizableImageWithCapInsets` is the proper method to use now.

Comment: Updated my answer, I would suggest playing around with the insets. I have had funny cases where one pixel can stretch/resize the image in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the residing mode for your image. The choices are `UIImageResizingModeStretch` and `UIImageResizingModeTile`.

The idea of having a stretchable image is so that you can have a small image file. You should consider using a smaller image to save space in your app bundle. Also, your left and right edge insets don't have to be in the middle. They should be just beyond the curve, which looks to be about 40 points in your image.

Here's the code to use to set the resizing mode:

```
bg = [bg resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this out: [Resizable UIImage where outside stretches and inside is kept the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217935/resizable-uiimage-where-outside-stretches-and-inside-is-kept-the-same?rq=1)

Basically the opposite of what you want. Hope it helps!